# Finding a simpler "local" lower bound for a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, rational-functions

I have obtained as the expression for some quantity the following gargantuan formula:

$$ \frac{k^8 + 3k^7 + 8k^6 + 3k^5 - 16k^4 - 32k^3 + 63k^2 - 34k + 6}{k^6 + 3k^5 + 6k^4 - 24k^2 + 21k - 5}$$.

What I really need is a (very) good lower bound on it, that will hopefully be a more manageable expression.

> Is there a systematic way of finding such bounds?

**The bound needs to be valid only on $[5,\infty]$.**

Comment: $k$ is in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: this expression ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ (for real $k$, and also for real positive $k$), so there is no lower bound.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Yes.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Sure, that's why I specified in my P.S. that I need actually a "local bound". I'll edit to make this point more prominent. Thanks.

Comment: As for a systematic way, your question reminds me of the problem of finding surrogate functions. A surrogate function is a function approximating the original one but cheaper to compute.

Comment: @Waldemar Can you please give a pointer to the literature on surrogate functions?

Comment: I heard of surrogate functions in optimization literature. There we say about surrogate objective functions (simply google the term or see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_model). This literature is not directly related to your problem as your particular function would not be generally regarded as computationally expensive. Nevertheless, there’s a clear analogy: you’ve got sth complex and want to approximate it with sth simpler. In your problem the basic asymptotic analysis suggests that for sufficiently large k the original function can be approximated by the function $k^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$k^2+1.98-2.8/k$$

lower bound, error $<0.02$ for all $k>5$

Comment: This looks great, but now I am curious - how did you obtain this result?

Comment: from the large-$k$ expansion

Comment: Do you mean the Taylor series? Or something else?

Comment: Taylor series around $1/k=0$ (it works because 1/5 is small enough respect to unity)

Answer (score 2):

The function blows up at approximately $-2.6$ and $+0.5$ and $+0.7$, 
and otherwise looks something like a parabola.
It is unclear what is meant by a "lower bound" for such a function.

     [image: FelixPlot]

     [image: FelxiPlot01]

Comment: Suppose we zoom in on $k\geq 5$ - can you suggest an adequate bound in that case?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: Well, then the lower bound is just the value of the expression at $k=5$, which is $\frac{373393}{14125} \approx 26.4$.

Comment: I want a bound which is also a function of $k$...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: I'm sorry, Felix, we are talking past one another. Your function is monotonically increasing $k \ge 5$.  I am not sure what it means to express this as a function of $k$.

Comment: Now I see, from Waldemar's comment and Carlo's answer.